# Why multiple PDO Fetch doesnt work

Tags: php, pdo

I have a problem with my code here.

Trying to fetch a menu for a site from mysql. 
The menu is on the top of the page and place it on the footer as well.

```
$menu=$start->query('SELECT * FROM menu WHERE visible=1');

while ($r_menu=$menu->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) 
{ 
echo "<li><a href='#'>" , $r_menu->menu , "</a></li>";
}
```

the result is fine, all the menu button is there.
The problem is when I copy paste the same code in the footer. Nothing happen. I tried to delete the top button and the button in the footer is appear.

Anything I miss here ?

***Just Added Example***

```
$menu=$start->query('SELECT * FROM menu WHERE visible=1');

echo "<p>First Menu: </p>";
while ($r_menu=$menu->fetchObject()) { echo "<a href='#'>" , $r_menu->menu , "</a><br>";}

echo "<p>Second Menu: </p>";
while ($r_menu=$menu->fetchObject()) { echo "<a href='#'>" , $r_menu->menu , "</a><br>";}
```

Only the First Menu is appear, the Second Menu just nothing there

Thanks before

Comment: are you sure you didn't close the connection somewhere? question's unclear/not enough code and there are missing `<ul></ul>` also.

Comment: there is a <ul></ul> on the original code. I copy paste the same code just on the line below, and the second code just doesnt work, nothing happen. Meaning, only the first block of code is working

Comment: you answered the latter and not the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the result set will get exhausted once you loop through the result set using `while()` loop. So if you try to loop through the result set again, it won't work.

The solution is, use [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method to save the entire result set in an array, and use this array multiple times in your code.

```
$menu=$start->query('SELECT * FROM menu WHERE visible=1');
$result = $menu->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row){
    echo "<li><a href='#'>" . $row['menu'] . "</a></li>";
}
```

Now you can use this `$result` array both the top and bottom section of your page.

Comment: @EddyHartono You're welcome! Glad I could help. :-) Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)